# Freeze column headers for a tabular report

Tags: reporting-services

I have selected “Keep header visible while scrolling” under Column Headers? But it not worked when I scrolling the report, my report type is tabular(not maxtrix) and the datasources have 105 rows data. Can you please help me on how to freeze the column header

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use **Advanced Mode** to set your header.

[image]

- Select your table
- On the Grouping window at the bottom, click on the down
  arrow/wedge/triangle/caron
- Click on **Advanced Mode** (the **only** option in the drop down menu).
- Click on the first **Static** line to select it
- In the properties window, set the **Fixed Data** to **True**

[image]